# How to write a SQL query for "how many different customers ordered more than 27 times?"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I found the customers and their total order numbers but I can't write the query to determine how many different customers

```
SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(*) 'number of orders' 
FROM Orders 
GROUP BY CustomerID 
HAVING COUNT(CustomerID) > 27
```

The output should return a single row including the number of customers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM Orders
      GROUP BY CustomerID
      HAVING COUNT(CustomerID) > 27
     ) o
```